# Have AirDrop auto-accept files from a certain other mac?

Tags: macos, airdrop

I have two macs in separate rooms and like to use AirDrop to transfer files between them, but having to accept on the receiver every time I send a file is annoying.

Is there a way to tell AirDrop always to accept files coming from a certain other Mac?

Answer (score 3):

TUAW just [featured an app called DropCopy](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/09/30/daily-mac-app-dropcopy/) yesterday. It has been around for about 4 years and one of the first sentences I read popped out and reminded me of this question.

> For one, DropCopy can auto-accept file transfers. Meaning, your recipient needn't be in front of his/her machine to initiate or accept a transfer. That's handy if you want some files to be waiting at a remote work station upon your arrival.

It's a bit of give-and-take. DropCopy DOES require all the computers to be on the same network. It does not set up a second channel AdHoc network even where supported, but it offers compatibility outside of Lion and lots of additional features.

> The way it works is similar to AirDrop. Just drag-and-drop your file onto the Dropzone and it'll show all the possible destinations. Participating machines must be running DropCopy on the same network. Simple.

Via TUAW's screenshot, DropCopy can also transfer your clipboard contents, send text messages, and also supports multiple computers.

DropCopy is free for the first 3 computers, can be downloaded [for free on the Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/dropcopy/id403411542?mt=12), [purchased from 10base-t interactive's website](http://10base-t.com/macintosh-software/dropcopy), and even has [an iOS version](http://10base-t.com/iphone-ipod-software/mobile-dropcopy/).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I've been able to tell, AirDrop is a 100% Finder/GUI driven interface. As evidenced by the fact that AirDrop does not enable unless you have the AirDrop Finder window open.

I gotta say, [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/) is pretty drop dead simple to set up on multiple computers. Afterwards you can just throw a file onto a folder stack of your choice in order to sync it across computers.

One of the best features of DropBox in recent versions is direct LAN sync. Instead of uploading the file to DropBox's servers, and re-downloading it on the other computer, it does upload to DropBox, but locally sends it to the other computer at the same time provided they are on the same network in some wired or wireless fashion.

Answer (score 1):

AirDrop sole purpose is the fast and easy creation of an ad-hoc network to manually and securely exchange files between physically close computers (think about situations like classrooms, Starbucks etc.).

In your situation, why don't you just create a shared folder which can be accessed (over WiFi or LAN) from either Mac or use the Drop Boxes of the individual accounts?

Comment: Because AirDrop is a million times easier to setup :) No fiddling with user accounts, permissions, network names and all that other stuff that was cool in the early 90's but shouldn't exist anymore on modern machines in favor of auto-discovery and ad-hoc sharing :)

Comment: Point taken, but assuming that the computers are in the same network already anyway, the use of each other's Drop Boxes isn't much more difficult than AirDrop. Nor is accessing the info panel (Get Info) of a folder and enabling the Shared option.

Answer (score 0):

What about iChat and enabling Bonjour accounts?  I use that here for about 50ish 10.6.8 Macs and a handful of Windows 7 PCs running [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im).

Still no auto-accept, though, until you also install the abandonware extra [Chax](http://www.ksuther.com/chax/).

A bit less than ideal, but works, and isn't restricted to OS X 10.7.